# Fast way to build array from originating arrays of different sizes

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, for-loop

I am building an array of (1000,100,100,100) from two arrays of sizes (1000,100,100,100) and (100,100,100). For this, I am using a for-loop to run the first entry (0 - 1000). However, my code (below) is still pretty slow and as a beginner, I was wondering whether there is more efficient way to do it.

```
n_train = 1000
Nx = 100
Ny = 100
Nt = 100

x = np.linspace(-Nx, Nx, 100)
y = np.linspace(-Ny, Ny, 100)
t = np.linspace(0, Nt-1, 100)

def gw(xx, yy, tt):
    num1 = tt - np.sqrt(xx**2+yy**2)
    denom = (tt**2-xx**2-yy**2)

    if denom < 0:
        denom1 = 0
    else:
        denom1 = np.sqrt(denom)

    kk = np.heaviside(num1,1)/(2*np.pi*denom1+1)

return (kk)

# Slow FOR-LOOP
for i_train in range (n_train):

    ugreen = np.array([gw(i, j, k) for k in t for j in y for i in x])
    Ugreen = ugreen.reshape(Nt, Ny, Nx)

    prob = randrange(2)
    Utot = UN[i_train,:,:,:] + Ugreen/1.75*prob
    Utot = (Utot - np.min(Utot))/(np.max(Utot)-np.min(Utot))

    Utot_green = 10*Ugreen/1.75*prob


    P[i_train,:,:,:] = Utot
    Pg[i_train,:,:,:]= Utot_green
```

Comment: Check out [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), it's targeted towards optimization problems like this

Comment: @C.Nivs, have you answered questions like this on CR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think several issues make this difficult. First of all, your code snippet does not compile, which IMHO is problematic in any programming language and corresponding forums.
And second, you do not explain what you are actually trying to calculate with your code. So I had to translate your code back to mathematics.
This brings me to the numpy-specific problem of this question.

Long story short: if you would have given some kind of mathematical equation in terms of vectors and matrices it would have been much easier to answer.

```
randrange
UN
P
PG
```

are not defined in your code.

In each loop you are evaluating Ugreen again, but I don't see that it changes in your loop. Move it outside the loop and save time.

```
gw()
```

can be written vectorized (and it is easily seen now what you are calculating - this should look very similar to your handwritten equation in your notes now):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sqrt

def gw(xx,yy,tt):
    return (0<=tt-sqrt(xx**2+yy**2))/(2*np.pi*sqrt(np.clip(tt**2-xx**2-yy**2,0,None))+1)

Ugreen = gw(x[:,None,None],y[None,:,None],t[None,None,:])
```

```
prob = randrange(2)#I assume this is some scalar
Utot = UN + Ugreen[None,:,:,:]/1.75*prob
Utot = (Utot - np.min(Utot,axis=0)[None,...])/(np.max(Utot,axis=0)[None,...]-np.min(Utot,axis=0)[None,...]
```

Here is a working example of what I think you are trying to calculate

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sqrt

def gw(x,y,t):
    return (0<=t-sqrt(x**2+y**2))/(2*np.pi*sqrt(np.clip(t**2-x**2-y**2,0,None))+1)

n_train = 1000
Nx = 100
Ny = 100
Nt = 100

x = np.linspace(-Nx, Nx, 100)
y = np.linspace(-Ny, Ny, 100)
t = np.arange(Nt)

Ugreen = gw(x[:,None,None],y[None,:,None],t[None,None,:])

prob = 2

Utot = np.random.random((n_train,Nt,Ny,Nx))
Utot += Ugreen[None,:,:,:]/1.75*prob
Utot /= (np.max(Utot,axis=0)[None,...]-np.min(Utot,axis=0)[None,...])
Utot -= np.min(Utot,axis=0)[None,...]/(np.max(Utot,axis=0)[None,...]-np.min(Utot,axis=0)[None,...])
```

I had to arange the `Utot`-evaluation in order not to run into memory-issues.
However, on my machine it runs within a few seconds.
It is certainly possible to optimize this further and I hope for some responses from other users to learn new things.

Some general hints on numpy:
IMHO if you want to see the true practical power of numpy it's better to forget everything you know about numerical programming from other languages than sticking with any thoughts/ideas/loop-wise thinking you might have.
My experience is that, yes numpy is very fast and this is very nice and so on, but it also makes your code extremely short, compact, and best for scientific work: extremely close to whatever complicated equation you might want to solve. One should start implementing equations as close to the paper as possible and optimize only where and when necessary.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answers and your effort. I am a complete beginner in SO and thats why i don't have any reputation to upvote your answer. But I really appreciate your patience and support in solving my problem. Thanks again.